# STreamlit how to implement a stateful ML app that doesnt rerun after every widget interaction

Tags: python, machine-learning, streamlit

I would like to implement a stateful ML app that doesnt rerun for every intreaction with a widget.

Flow of app:
Step 1: Enter filepath and upload data onto dataframe on click of a button.
Step 2: Show sample data
Step 3: Show descriptive stats
Step 4: Plot histogram for selected feature dynamically on selection from selectbox.

When I select a new variable apart from the default selection for step 4 plot, the entire script reruns.
How do I save state information such that when I am at step 4, everything above this doesnt get rerun i.e step1,2,3 shouldnt be called again. Only what I am interacting with in step 4.
Kindly help me out.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st
import pyspark
from pyspark import *
from PIL import Image
from io import StringIO
import st_state_patch

def load_data(ss,uploaded_file):
    df = ss.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load(uploaded_file)
    return df

def sample_data(df,widget):
    df_sample = pd.DataFrame(df.head(5))
    df_sample.columns = df.columns
    widget.dataframe(df_sample)
    
def descriptive_stats(df,widget):
    df_desc = df.summary().toPandas()
    widget.dataframe(df_desc)
    
def hist_plot(df,col,widget):
    df_plot = df.select(col).toPandas().iloc[:,0]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.hist(df_plot,density = False, bins = 50)
    widget.pyplot(fig)

def main():
    sparkapp = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master('local[4]').appName('No-code Spark Pipeline').getOrCreate()
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    st.title("No-Code ML Spark Pipeline")
    st.subheader('1. Upload file (csv)')
    uploaded_file = st.text_input("Provide local file path")
    upload_button1 = st.button('Upload')
    st.caption('Sample data')
    upload_cont1 = st.empty()
    white_background = Image.open('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/white_600_240.png')
    upload_cont1.image(white_background)
    # Call load data
    if upload_button1:
        df = load_data(sparkapp,uploaded_file)
        sample_data(df, upload_cont1)
    # Call sample data
    
    st.subheader('2. Exploratory Data Analytics')
    st.caption('Descriptive statistics')
    eda_cont1 = st.empty()
    eda_cont1.image(white_background,use_column_width=True)
    # Call descriptive stats
    if upload_button1:
        descriptive_stats(df, eda_cont1)         
    st.caption('Histogram / Frequency plot')
    eda_sel_feat = st.selectbox('Select feature to be displayed', options = df.columns)
    eda_cont2 = st.empty()
    eda_cont2.image(white_background,use_column_width=True)
    # Call hist plot
    if upload_button1:
        hist_plot(df,eda_sel_feat,eda_cont2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit has a feature called caching (@st.cache) by hashing the data so computation won't repeat always for similar functions But in this scenario, We are using PySpark.

Streamlit can't hash PySpark functions due to spark's dependence on Java.